# Can staggered manage view based on the content's width and scroll as vertical?

Tags: android, layout, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I am using staggered view to create view tag which will contain text-view but I am facing a problem to manage my content If I am using Staggered Horizontal Manager this is managing my tags based on content's width as I want but the scrollable is horizontal.

[image]

And if I use staggered Vertical Manager then it's managing content based on height.
**Can I customize staggered view to manage these tags based on their width but scrollable would be vertical?**

Please help to solve this, I would be thankful.

Comment: I just realized that I have to create a custom layout manager. I will start it soon

Comment: I found this library today you can use it https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem Abdul Rizwan ?